# ¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?

Tags: discusión, títulos-de-preguntas

Empecé a usar SOes porque me lo sugirieron desde SO en inglés, sin embargo aún  cuando tengo dudas, recurro rápidamente al sitio en inglés. Al pensar en este comportamiento, he notado que cuando tengo un problema escribo directamente el error o lo  más cercano al error para encontrar la respuesta, y usualmente ese error está como el titulo de una respuesta en el sitio en inglés.

Ahora, cuando visito el sitio en español, noto con inquietud que los títulos distan mucho de ser descriptivos, y aunque la pregunta es muy interesante, o puede aportar mucho al sitio, o ya ha sido respondida, el título, si yo tuviera un problema similar haría imposible que yo lo encontrara. Por ejemplo,
[Problema con llamada de funcion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58102/problema-con-llamada-de-funcion) trata sobre este error: `cannot call member function int CJornada::PuntsTotalsJornada(CJornada&) without object`.

Pues bien, tal vez no sea muy importante, pero si lo es, ¿cuánto énfasis se le debe dar a la edición del título por sobre otras cosas relacionadas a la manera en que se escribe o no se escribe dentro de la pregunta?

Bien, es sólo una inquietud :) Gracias

Comment: ¡Excelente punto! No podría estar más de acuerdo en poner énfasis en la importancia del título.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, hay que enfatizarlo más. Hay que pensar en términos de SEO para los futuros usuarios que puedan utilizar el sitio. Da gusto entrar en una pregunta sabiendo ya de qué va. Incluso en esta pregunta mismo, qué poco descriptivo habría sido "títulos preguntas" y cuanto ayuda el título que pusiste.

Comment: Lo que a veces hago es leer la pregunta y reemplazar el titulo por uno que yo creo que es más descriptivo. Creo que esa tarea (por el momento) es responsabilidad de todos los que moderamos el sitio (hasta que los usuarios se comprendan la importancia de un buen titulo)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

El título es igual de importante que el cuerpo de la pregunta.

## Explicación

Los editores están en libertad de decidir a que dedican el tiempo que destinan a mejorar una pregunta. Lo ideal es que las ediciones se lleven a cabo de forma integral, es decir, lo ideal es que una edición mejore todo lo que haya que mejorar en una pregunta.

Si hay una excelente descripción del problema en el cuerpo de la pregunta, pero el título es malo, muchos podrían asumir que el contenido también es malo y no leer el contenido, por otro lado, si el título es "muy bueno", digamos interesante, pero el contenido es malo, los lectores se decepcionarán y el sitio perderá relevancia y credibilidad.

**Anexo**

De [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> #### Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico
>
> El título es la primera cosa que los que potenciales contestadores
>   verán, y si tu título no es interesante, ellos no leerán el resto. Así
>   que considera:
>
> - **Pretende que le estás hablando a un colega ocupado** y que tienes que
>     resumir toda la pregunta en una oración: ¿qué detalles puedes incluir
>     que ayudarán a otros a identificar y resolver tu problema? Incluye
>     cualquier mensaje de error, APIs clave o circunstancias inusuales que
>     hacen tu pregunta diferente de preguntas similares que ya existen en
>     el sitio.
> - **¡La ortografía, la gramática y la puntuación son importantes!**
>     Recuerda, esta es la primera parte de tu pregunta que otros verán -
>     quieres dar una buena impresión. Si no te sientes cómodo escribiendo
>     en Español, pregunta a un amigo que revise la lectura.
>
> Si tienes problemas resumiendo el problema, **escribe el título al
>   último** - algunas veces escribir el resto de la pregunta primero puede
>   facilitar a describir el problema.
>
> Ejemplos:
>
> - **Mal**: C# Confusión Matemática
> - **Bien**: ¿Por qué usar float en lugar de int me da diferentes resultados cuando todas mis entradas son enteros?
> - **Mal**: [php] duda de sesión
> - **Bien**: ¿Cómo puedo redirigir a los usuarios a diferentes páginas basado en datos de la sesión en PHP?
> - **Mal**: Android problemas con if else
> - **Bien**: ¿Por qué str == "value" evalúa a falso cuando le asigno "value" a str?