# ¿Qué significa "no deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título"?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, títulos-de-preguntas

En [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) dice

> "No deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título"

y más adelante

> La única ocasión en la que debes usar etiquetas en tu título es cuando son orgánicos al tono conversacional del título.

¿Qué significa esto?

Comment: Sugiero retitular a "necesito soporte sobre..." :)

Comment: Mejor, que sea: *Soporte - Etiquetas - ¿Qué significa “no deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título”?*

Comment: Yo estaba pensando en algo como `[¡Que alguien me explique!][Soporte][Dudas][etiquetas][títulos][no forzar]`

Answer (score 4):

En síntesis, la recomendación es que los títulos deben ser una frase correctamente redactada, que pueda leerse de forma fácil y fluida sobre todo que describa de forma breve, concisa y precisa el contenido de la pregunta. Puedes incluir el nombre del lenguaje, tecnología, concepto, método pero integrado en la redacción.

---

En los tiempos iniciales de la comunicación digital y hoy día en ciertos foros se recomienda colocar una etiqueta en el asunto o título de la comunicación, es por ello que es común que se publiquen preguntas en SOes y otros sitios de Stack Exchange siguiendo esta práctica. Sin embargo, los sitios de Stack Exchange cuentan con características especiales para el manejo de ciertas etiquetas.

El término etiqueta tiene muchas connotaciones. Puede referirse a una palabra clave, tópico, categoría, estado, entre otras cosas. Generalmente se refiere a algo que nos ayuda a clasificar una publicación.

En el contexto de Stack Exchange podríamos decir que las "etiquetas de la comunidad" a las que usualmente nos referimos simplemente como "etiquetas" son aquellas que han sido creadas al publicar o editar una pregunta por un miembro de la comunidad con el privilegio correspondiete para hacerlo.

No está "prohibido incluir etiquetas en los títulos. Lo que está "prohivido" son las formas para destacarlas del resto del contenido, por ejemplo,

- colocarlas al inicio seguidas de algún separador como dos puntos `:`, un guión `-`, una diagonal `/`, una barra `|`, entre otros
- colocarlas entre corchetes `[...]`, llaves `{...}`, paréntesis `(...)`, guiones `-...-`
- colocarlas al final precedidas por `en` o  un separador como los mencionados arriba.

En el artículo de ayuda en cuestión se incluyen ejemplos de los casos a evitar.

**Pregunta relacionada**

[¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/65)

---

La cita completa de En [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2462/65) es, énfasis mío en las líneas incluidas en la pregunta:

> #### ¿Debería usar etiquetas en títulos?
>
> **No deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título**. Puesto que las etiquetas que aparecen debajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas mismas
>   son indexadas por los motores de búsqueda junto con el contenido de la
>   pregunta, puedes confiar en que otras personas serán capaces de
>   encontrar tu pregunta basado en etiquetas que ellos siguen o buscan.
>   Adicionalmente, las etiquetas aparecen en la página de la pregunta, de
>   modo que otras personas las tomará en cuenta al contestar tu pregunta.
>
> Evita insertar etiquetas en los títulos en cualquiera de los
>   siguientes formatos:
>
> - [etiqueta]: [título de la pregunta]
> - [título de la pregunta] -- [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta]
> - [título de la pregunta] in (sic) [etiqueta]<sup>1</sup>
> - [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [título de la pregunta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta]
> - [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta] [etiqueta] -  [etiqueta]
>
> **La única ocasión en la que debes usar etiquetas en tu título es cuando son orgánicos al tono conversacional del título**.
>
> Por ejemplo, en lugar de escribir, "JavaScript, jQuery: Cuándo debo
>   usar uno u otro?" – que fuerza las etiquetas en el título – puedes
>   comunicar la misma información en un tono conversacional:
>
> ¿Puedo usar jQuery para "foo" en el "baz", o estoy atascado usando
>   JavaScript plano?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Ya [se solicitó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2462/65) la corrección

Comment: correguir _prohivido_ por _prohibido_.

Comment: @IsaacNewton Gracias por la observación. Procuraré aplicar esa corrección la próxima vez que edite esta respuesta.