# ¿Es correcto editar el titulo para poner "[SOLUCIONADO]"?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas

No lo había visto antes, pero no sé si quiero esperar a que empiecen a proliferar este tipo de ediciones. Al parecer el OP [de esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88122/solucionadocomo-pasar-a-un-fragment-desde-una-activity-con-android-studio), resolvió su propio problema y se auto respondió. Después editó el título de su pregunta y al principio puso "[SOLUCIONADO]".

No recuerdo ver por ninguna parte en el centro de ayuda algo que hable de esto. Además, el marcar una respuesta como aceptada es el método que debemos seguir para indicar que una pregunta está solucionada.

¿Está bien hacerlo? ¿Debemos dejarlo pasar? ¿Debemos educar para que no se siga haciendo?

Comment: Yo también he editado un par de títulos con esa leyenda. Los he quitado inmediatamente los veo. Eso es una práctica de otros foros, que no aplican para esta comunidad. Es por eso que se diseñó el link `✓` para aceptar una pregunta que ha sido resuelta.

Comment: Ya estaba revertida la edición pero le he dejado un mensaje al OP comentandoselo. He visto algún que otro caso y en SOen lo he visto incluso más, generalmente es una costubre adquirida de foros y otros sitios similares. Como comenta Rubén en su respuesta, esto no está permitido, ya existe una forma "legal" de hacer esto en SO que es aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: De hecho en SO hay distintas propuestas para directamente bloquear este texto cuando se ponga como título y conminarles a aceptar/publicar respuesta en ese caso: [Suggest to post answer / accept one when changing title to “Solved”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294924/1983854) y [\[Updated\] Actively prevent this in title \[NOT SOLVED YET\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/1983854)

Comment: Dicho lo cual, no encuentro ningún caso ahora mismo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3Asolucionado

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, de ninguna manera está bien hacerlo, no debemos dejarlo pasar y sí, debemos educar para que no se siga haciendo.

Tal vez te sirva

[¿Qué significa "no deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2464/65),

así como también

[¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/65)

Answer (score 10):

Realmente, por propia experiencia, puedo decir que yo también cometí el mismo error en SOen cuando empecé.

Me corrigieron, me dijeron la forma correcta de actuar y a partir de entonces ya no volví a cometer ese error.

¿De dónde saque la idea? Me sonaba que en otros foros de preguntas/respuestas las personas editaban sus títulos para que la gente supiera que ya estaban solucionados. Pensé que era la manera correcta hasta que me dijeron como actuar.

Por lo tanto, lo que yo haría:

- Editar la pregunta para eliminar el mensaje de `[SOLUCIONADO]`.
- Indicarle al OP que no se debería de hacer así en este sitio.
- Explicarle la forma correcta de actuar en este sitio.