# Al preguntar o editar escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas

Tags: discusión, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas

Me he fijado en que muchas preguntas contienen títulos del tipo "*ayuda con X*" o "*Y no me funciona*", etc.

Creo que debemos mejorar esta parte: el espacio del título es muy reducido y todo lo que no es imprescindible, acaba siendo ruido. Para mí, sobra, vaya. Además, un título con mala descripción hace más difícil encontrar la pregunta en el futuro y, por ende, se duplica la información o, en el peor de los casos, se acaba perdiendo en el mar de preguntas que nos rodea.

En general creo que hacemos una buena labor a la hora de dejar el cuerpo de la pregunta en un buen estado, pero la parte del título rara vez veo que se toque.

Algún ejemplos serían [Apache + php vs nginx + php vs nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/120199/83) o [Problema con clearTimeout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/120131/83). En nuestra estresantísima vida, es algo molesto tener que entrar en una pregunta para ver de qué va. ¿Acaso no es esto como el título de un correo electrónico, que siempre se agradece que nos dé una pista de lo que se debatirá?

Por ello, estoy buscando las versiones más "sangrantes" y editando el título para ceñirlo a la pregunta en sí.

Si alguien tiene también ganas, puede buscar palabras como "help", "ayuda", etc en las preguntas (truco: escribid [`is:q title:ayuda`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3Aayuda) para filtrar las preguntas, donde `q` quiere decir *q*uestion).

Siempre, además, deberíamos añadir todas las etiquetas, y solamente esas, que describan el contexto de la pregunta. ¡Esto también ayuda a que encuentren más fácilmente!

Comment: Buena iniciativa. Yo si trato de mejorar el título de la pregunta si veo que es poco descriptivo, pero lo cierto es que en numerosas ocasiones la pregunta es tan amplia o de tan baja calidad que es bastante difícil hacerlo. Pero no está de mas intentarlo.

Comment: Me leiste la mente @fedorqui. Si hay algo que me asombra es el poco marketing que se hacen de sus propias preguntas... Agregaría algo: **a quienes responden**, por favor, traten de modificar el título. Son quienes más tiempo le dedicaron, los que mejor entienden el problema planteado, y quienes pueden darle el mejor y más específico título!!!!!!

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, en lo personal, me resulta más fácil editar el cuerpo de la pregunta que el título. Este último tiene gran "visibilidad" y me "asusta" un poco modificarlo y no lograra mejorarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Completamente de acuerdo y en apoyo a esta iniciativa he colocado una [propuesta de advertencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3453/65) en [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/65)

P.D.

Hoy día tenemos 584 preguntas con `ayuda` en el título.

Por cierto, me parece que es suficiente con utilizar [title:ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aayuda) pues sólo las preguntas tienen título. Tal vez agregar [closed:0 votes:n] para limitar a sólo las preguntas abiertas y con un número n mínimo de votos o [closed:0 votes:0..0] para preguntas abiertas con cero puntos.

Por cierto, si la pregunta es mala, antigua y con cero puntos en lugar de editar el título quizás deberíamos votar negativo que sean borradas automáticamente.

Relacionado

- [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/65)

Comment: Se me ocurre que hagamos tareas semanales, como por ejemplo dejar la lista de preguntas con [`title:ayuda`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aayuda) a cero.

Comment: @fedorqui En este momento tenemos 754 preguntas. No sé si sea conveniente que en una semana reduzcamos este número a cero, pero definitivamente tener una meta y darle seguimiento sería muy útil.