# ¿Tiene la comunidad de SOes un bajo conocimiento? ¿Cómo mejorarlo?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

¿La comunidad de SOes tiene un bajo conocimiento? Creo que eso no es cierto totalmente, pero comparando las preguntas del sitio de español con el de inglés las preguntas son  mucho mas avanzadas en SO. ¿Qué podemos hacer para mejorar?

Comment: Darle tiempo. Tiempo para tener más usuarios y esperar a que más expertos vengan con dudas o las resuelvan.

Comment: Irónicamente esta pregunta no sigue los lineamientos de [ask]. Sería bueno que una pregunta sobre cómo mejorar fuera ejemplo de lo una buena pregunta debe ser :) Por ejemplo, falta indicar detalles que ayuden a otros a identificar y resolver el problema, que en este caso podría ser poner ejemplos de las preguntas comparadas entre los sitios en español e inglés, mencionar otras preguntas de Meta relacionadas.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lois6b, no podemos compararnos con [so] que tiene ya 10 años de vida, al principio las preguntas ahí eran igual o peores que las nuestras, por ejemplo esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c) del mismísimo Jeff Atwood que hoy en día, incluso aquí se la cerraría y llenaría de votos negativos.

Comment: @KacosPro usted tiene razon, revise el enlace de la pregunta y es bastante basica, entonces solo es cuestion de tiempo

Comment: @KacosPro precisamente Jeff Atwood fue el que apostó por eliminar todo lo malo, es raro que esta siga viva. Siempre se comenta que Joel Spolsky (el otro fundador) era el más partidario a aceptarlo todo, mientras que Jeff era más del parecer de ser más exigente. En la dirección solo queda Joel, por lo que parece que su visión fue la ganadora. [Más sobre el debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/1983854).

Answer (score 7):

- En SO actualmente hay más de 16 millones de preguntas visibles y recibe unas siete mil diarias ([fuente](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#questions)). Está a punto de cumplir 10 años de vida.
- En SOes a día de hoy hay unas 60 mil, con unas 120 diarias (misma fuente). Tiene dos años y medio de vida.

Los problemas que uno se puede encontrar como programador son muchos, pero los más comunes son finitos. Entiendo que por SO ya ha pasado suficiente gente como para que ya los tengan cubiertos, por lo que las preguntas *fáciles* ya no se formulan porque la respuesta ya está allí y rápidamente se marcan como duplicadas (y se borran muchas veces).

En SOes estamos creciendo (creo) y poco a poco se va expandiendo el campo cubierto por las preguntas. En un tiempo, las cosas *sencillas* probablemente ya estarán hechas y las preguntas nuevas deberán ser algo más complejas para no ser cerradas como duplicadas.

Puede que esto suena un poco autocomplaciente, pero no, creo que hay muchas cosas que debemos hacer nosotros para que el nivel suba sin esperar a que lo haga por arte de magia. A bote pronto, se me ocurre:

- Editar, editar y editar. [Poner títulos descriptivos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/83) para que las preguntas se encuentren mejor, tanto desde los buscadores como en el sitio mismo a la hora de encontrar duplicados.
- Votar positivamente lo bueno.
- Indicar lo malo, editarlo y, si no hay más remedio, votarlo negativamente para que quede claro que no es correcto.
- Predicar con el ejemplo formulando preguntas potentes, [incluso respondiéndonos a nosotros mismos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).
- Intentar captar, seducir a nuevos usuarios. Es bueno tener usuarios estudiantes que empiezan a programar, pero también es fantástico (y necesario) tener a gurús ([como tiene SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16137/209901)) para empezar a ser *el sitio* de referencia.