# Títulos de baja calidad en preguntas

Tags: discusión, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas, advertencias-en-preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

He visto muchas veces preguntas que tienen un título que comienzan con *Ayuda con*, como las siguientes(estas preguntas son las que he encontrado actualmente activas):

- [¿Cómo se pueden crear nuevos DIV'S?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181615/ayuda-con-estos-div)
- [Ayuda con android studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181622/ayuda-con-android-studio)
- [ayuda con varios DIV y creacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181556/ayuda-con-varios-div-y-creacion)
- [Ayuda con expresiones regulares en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/ayuda-con-expresiones-regulares-en-java)
- [Ayuda sobre codigo de barras en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181892/ayuda-sobre-codigo-de-barras-en-android)

más preguntas con títulos similares:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pienso que ese tipo de títulos no son adecuados o por lo menos es innecesario ya que SO sirve para dar ayuda, generando redundancia. Este tipo de títulos evitan que el autor se esfuerce por colocar un título de calidad.

Esto dificulta las búsqueda de duplicados, buscar soluciones, etc.

En SO en inglés no se permite crear o editar títulos que inicien con *Problem with* o frases similares enviandote a revisar [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648)

¿se podría implementar esa funcionalidad aquí?

Titulos que pienso que deberian ser bloqueados:

- *Ayuda con*
- *Problema con*

Si es asi tambien me podrian ayudar aumentando la lista de frases.

Comment: Relacionado 1) [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/65) 2) [Escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/65)

Comment: La parte de "ayuda" ya [se propuso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3453/65) en [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/65)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3299/advertencias-en-preguntas-potencialmente-problem%c3%a1ticas)

Comment: @Rubén me parece genial, ojalá que pronto se implemente ya que los títulos son una parte importante en la pregunta ya que atraen a los que queremos ayudar a responder las preguntas, aparte de ahorrarnos tiempo y no reescribir la misma respuestas.

Comment: @Rubén tambien deberian estar frases triviales como *hola*

Comment: Si no lo has hecho aún, pasa por el hilo "Advertencias..." y vota/comenta las propuestas. Las que se muestran aún no se han implementado.

Comment: Es por esto que es importante ayudar sugiriendo a algunos usuarios edición de su pregunta y revisar [ask], para que las preguntas en realidad sean de ayuda a la comunidad, iniciando por títulos más descriptivos que ayuden a encontrar información.

Comment: @Jorgesys y ese sería el camino ideal, pero si revisas quienes crean ese tipo de preguntas: son nuevos usuarios, muchas veces le he señalado que revisen [ask] y el [tour], pero no lo hacen ya que no lo ven relevante, recién se dan cuenta de su importancia cuando responden preguntas o son usuarios con más experiencia. Asi que una forma sencilla de evitar ello es implementar dicha funcionalidad. :)

Comment: otra pregunta similar :https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182746/ayuda-con-utilizacion-de-variables-y-signos-en-c

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Prohibamos la palabra "ayuda" en los títulos de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4759/prohibamos-la-palabra-ayuda-en-los-t%c3%adtulos-de-las-preguntas), ¡esto se completó!