# Prohibamos la palabra "ayuda" en los títulos de las preguntas

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, títulos-de-preguntas, advertencias-en-preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

> <sub>Esta es una propuesta de [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva).
>
> **▲ Votar positivamente** quiere decir que **estás de acuerdo** con la propuesta.
>
> **▼ Votar negativamente** quiere decir que **NO estás de acuerdo** con la propuesta.
>
> Puedes responder o comentar si quieres, pero no es necesario.</sub>

---

Actualmente, y gracias a lo descrito en [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83), si una pregunta tiene la palabra "ayuda" en el título aparece la siguiente sugerencia al ir a enviarla:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Usualmente los títulos que incluyen "ayuda" son demasiado generales. En este sitio es recomendable que estos sean breves pero específicos e interesantes. Para ideas sobre cómo redactar el título de una pregunta consulta [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Es una sugerencia, lo que quiere decir que se puede enviar sin problema (y más de mil resultados de [`is:q title:"ayuda"`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3A%22ayuda%22) lo corroboran.

En cambio, en Stack Overflow en inglés está prohibido directamente:

> [image]

Donde el texto en cuestión dice:

> These words are not allowed in titles: 'help'.. See [Writing Good Titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/209901).

Es decir: *Estas palabras no están permitidas en el título...* y luego presenta un enlace a una página de MetaSO muy bien detallada.

---

Por todo ello, y dado que en publicaciones tipo [Exámenes, ejercicios y estudiantes caraduras](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4745/83) se está incidiendo reiteradamente en que nos topamos con demasiadas preguntas de "haz un ejercicio para mí", **propongo que se prohíba el texto `ayuda.*` de los títulos de las preguntas para intentar atajar la gran cantidad de estas que llegan con muy baja calidad**.

El mensaje que se podría incluir es:

> Estas palabras no están permitidas en los títulos: "ayuda". Recomendamos leer [¿Cómo escribo un buen título?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4774/).

A todos nos toca también [Al preguntar o editar escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/83).

Comment: Buena propuesta! me alegro que venga de mi post, pero ya que estamos, yo prohibiría también **Examen y Ejercicio**

Comment: @NicolasOñate propongo ir partido a partido e ir sacando una propuesta cada vez, o al menos una pregunta por propuesta para que sea lo más atómico y consensuado posible

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedo votar mas que una vez por esta propuesta. Estoy completamente a favor.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' para mi esas tres palabras son hermanas, pero te haré caso

Comment: le di sextuple click al boton positivo... ya lo podemos aprobar???

Comment: @Pikoh lo mismo los moderadores podéis darle visibilidad al debate poniéndole la etiqueta [meta-tag:destacado]

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' listo ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pikoh !! Oh capitán mi capitán

Comment: o sea, que no aceptariamos tampoco titulos como "mi aplicacion no muestra los mensajes de `ayuda`" ? o "no se suma el `ejercicio` al total del libro de contabilidad" o "la consulta no devuelve al alumno del `examen` de matematicas" ?? no veo bien restringir como tal "palabras" sueltas.

Comment: @Jakala mi propuesta sugiera prohibir solamente la palabra "ayuda" (de hecho `ayuda\w*`). Puede que haya casos particulares como el que comentas, pero son absolutamente los menos. Te animo a mirar el [listado de preguntas con título "ayuda"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3A%22ayuda%22) para ver que la grandísima mayoría de casos son preguntas muy pobres cuyo título no es ni representativo ni útil. De los 1295 casos que veo ahora mismo, no he encontrado preguntas con necesidad real de usar la palabra "ayuda" y sí muchísimas que con un título sin esa palabra ganarían mucho.

Comment: entiendo la propuesta. Pero el restringir palabras sueltas, o patrones que cumplen ciertas frases, siempre me ha parecido un mal habito para buscar/filtrar/eliminar (en general). Eso afecta a la forma de escribir de la gente, y obligas al usuario a cambiar su pregunta. En algunos casos puede estar bien, pero en otros puede que al final la persona no pueda expresarse correctamente.

Comment: Podria entender ese filtrado si el usuario tiene una puntuacion arbitraria (pongamos por ej, 1000 puntos). Eso significa que tienes experiencia en el sitio, y tienes que escribir las cosas bien. Ok. Pero a alguien que entra primero, puedes echarle atras, y hacer que se olvide de SO (y perder a un posible buen colaborador)

Comment: @Jakala precisamente es eso lo que busco: obligar al usuario a cambiar su pregunta. Indicando en que ciertas palabras no pueden usarse obligamos a que el AP (autor de la pregunta) busque maneras más descriptivas de expresar su problema. Si no es capaz de explicar su problema correctamente sin usar la palabra "ayuda", muy probablemente la pregunta tendrá un valor bastante bajo y, por ende, menos capacidad de ser respondida y de que sirva de ayuda para otros en el futuro.

Comment: Me parece adecuado y estoy de acuerdo con @NicolasOñate en que se deberían prohibir también las palabras **Examen y Ejercicio**

Comment: @Jakala a todo esto, estoy de acuerdo con tus ideas. Ahora bien, la tecnología de [se] solo permite filtrar en base a expresiones regulares en alguno de los bloques (título, cuerpo, etiquetas) y emitir advertencia o prohibición. Son las herramientas con las que contamos

Comment: Me suscribo a lo que dice @Jakala. Si alguien no entiende bien, por ejemplo, una función de ayuda (bueno, puede usar "helper function", pero no sé si queda "bonito"), o quiere implementar un botón de ayuda, estaría limitando cómo escribir un título descriptivo. Sugeriría más bien prohibir "Ayuda" como la primera palabra, o en su defecto "Ayuda con" en cualquier parte. Encontré, por ejemplo, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/360402/ayuda-con-b%c3%basqueda-en-agenda-y-panel-de-ayuda , que, a pesar de tener la palabra "ayuda" mal usada al principio, si se usa correctamente al final.

Comment: Sería bueno también quitar las relacionadas, como `necesito`, `por favor`, `alguien`. Bueno, en este último puede ser una advertencia... Pero la advertencia tiene que ir mientras se está escribiendo, no luego de enviarla.

Comment: @ArtEze Hay muchas palabras relacionadas a preguntas de baja calidad, aunque eso creo que deberiamos contemplarlo en otro post de meta, uno que contemple todas las palabras que pueden llevar a una pregunta de baja calidad, simplemente para tenerlas ahi reunidas, ya que con las tuyas mas las que propuse ya son 5

Comment: He añadido un nuevo post para ir recogiendo las palabras conflictivas https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4770/palabras-que-pueden-derivar-en-preguntas-de-baja-calidad

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con una propuesta de @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' . No sé qué pensar (jeje, mentiras, sí sé. Esta buenísima esta propuesta). Es importante entonces ser más estrictos con todos los _pioneros_ que le añaden basura o una colección de keywords al título (y al cuerpo de la pregunta) pa saltarse los filtros automáticos

Comment: @Alfabravo jajaja ;-)

Comment: cerrar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3574/83 como duplicada de esta cuando se complete

Comment: Esto seria una _ayuda_ a los usuarios nuevos

Comment: Just dropping by to confirm this is on the CM team's backlog, and that we'll will get back to you once this is assigned to someone.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, @Adam!

Comment: Estaba de acuerdo con este punto hasta que lei el comentario de Jakala. El tiene razón, estariamos perjudicando a una minoria solo por que "queremos mejores titulos"? Estariamos privando a gente de preguntar cosas como las que el mismo Jakala dice...

Comment: @DanteS. como se comentó extensamente por aquí en su momento, la clave está en cuánto perjudica y cuánto beneficia. Si evitamos (como parece que está pasando) 100 malos títulos a costa de impedir uno bueno, creo que el esfuerzo vale la pena. Dicho lo cual, esto es un filtro sobre el título: no impide que una pregunta se haga, sino que contenga esta palabra allí.

Comment: Es verdad, pero después no estaría bueno que recibamos mal una pregunta por que su titulo no es el adecuado por que la palabra "ayuda" no puede estar...

Comment: @DanteS. no entiendo tu comentario. Una pregunta en el sitio principal actualmente no puede tener la palabra "ayuda" en el título, después de que se implementara lo que solicitaba en esta pregunta de Meta.

Comment: Lo se, pero igual, no recibamos mal una pregunta que dice "quiero que aparesca este mensaje en mi ventana" cuando en realidad el titulo debia ser "quiero que aparesca este mensaje de ayuda en mi ventana"

Comment: @DanteS. absolutamente de acuerdo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El 25 de septiembre de 2020 esto se implementó por parte de Adam Lear, que puso [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) a la pregunta.

Veámoslo en acción:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es, el texto que aparece es:

> El título no puede contener “ayuda”.
>
> Estas palabras no están permitidas en los títulos: "ayuda". Recomendamos leer [¿Cómo escribo un buen título?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4774/).

Veo que de hecho se implementó utilizando la expresión regular `ayuda.*`, de modo que todo lo que empiece por "ayuda", tipo *ayudadme* también lanza el mensaje:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este cambio tiene efecto también sobre las preguntas que ya existen. Por ello, si vamos a alguna de las preguntas que contiene el texto [`is:q title:"ayuda"`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3A%22ayuda%22) y la editamos, nos obligará a cambiar el título para que deje de aparecer la palabra.

Comment: ¡Excelente tutorial! Vine para dar un poco más de instrucción pero veo que has lo has hecho ya y con calidad.

Answer (score 4):

De acuerdo. Creo que este tipo de propuestas (con un mensaje amable de validación), invitarán al usuario a que haga una mejor concreción del problema para reflejar exactamente lo que necesita.

Answer (score -8):

Como va ha aprender una persona si no la dejan cometer errores?, estoy seguro que la mayoría de las personas que votan SI tienen muchos años de experiencia en este tipo de paginas de "ayuda", y por experiencia saben como realizar las preguntas, entonces como ya sabemos que cansado soportar a los que no saben?. Creo que deben ser mas humildes y en realidad enseñar y de paso ayudan.

Comment: Bienvenido a Meta. Esta respuesta es demasiado general y no está clara la relación que tiene con lo que se está proponiendo, sería bueno que la hicieras más enfocada a lo que se ha propuesto. Por otro lado ¿qué tiene que ver la humildad con prohibir la palabra ayuda en los títulos de las preguntas?

Comment: No me gusta prohibir, quien diablos creo que soy para prohibir?, prefiero enseñar, dar razones por la que no lo debo usar

Comment: @OscarNogales La idea del sitio es conseguir una base de conocimientos mediante preguntas y respuestas. Unos conocimientos **que sirva para todos**. Un título como `AYUDAAAA !!` ... ¿ A quien crees que servirá ? ¿ De que forma un usuario **distinto del que formuló la pregunta** pero con **el mismo problema** podrá encontrar la publicación ? De ahí la **necesidad** de títulos **descriptivos**. Cuanto mas descriptivos, mejor.

Comment: No creo que sea el lugar para polemizar, pero veamolo asi: Oscar- Ayudaaaa mi consulta no carga en mi datatable - BetaZ: Oscar no colocaste el codigo, por favor hazlo, y evita utilizar la palabra ayuda para que otro usuario con el mismo problema pueda encontrar la solucion - Oscar: Ups que pena....no sabia - BetaZ: No te preocupes coloca el codigo haber si  te podemos ayudar... De esa forma yo no lo vuelvo hacer, pero es mas facil prohibir porque yo si se como se debe preguntar y los demas deben aprender,

Comment: Otro diálogo, y este es **100% real**: Usuario: Ayudaaaa por XXX - Yo: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Por favor, evita colocar cosas importantes como imágenes. Incluye el código relevante como texto. - Usuario: ¿ Para que quieres el código ? Ya te he puesto una imagen con mi problema. - Yo: pero es que las imágenes se pueden perder, y algunos usuarios no pueden verlas correctamente. - Usuario: Pero si no tienes mas que hazer zoom ...

Comment: En resumen: **es mucho mas rápido y eficaz prohibir el hacer algo que el intentar convencer de que no se haga**. Y el ejemplo de diálogo que te he puesto no es un caso aislado. Ni mucho menos.

Comment: Como mencione ayer, este no es el sitio para polemizar, me encantaria pero no, y en el caso de trauma, que es real, de que hubiera servido prohibir la palabra ayuda?, y difiero contigo, es mucho mas rapido y eficaz enseña.

Comment: Me hubiera ahorrado 20 minutos de intentar razonar con una piedra; me habría ahorrado el pensaminento de *No se ni para que lo intento. A votar para cerrar y listo*. Y ese tiempo perdido, se habría empleado a responder a alguien que **si** entiende el concepto de `norma`. Que a veces parece que tenemos que estar agradecidos de poder ayudar. Que no es tan difícil. Algunas palabras no se pueden usar en el título. No hay mucho mas que explicar.

Comment: Muchos redirigen a usuarios que cometen este tipo de errores a links como "como preguntar?" cuyo objetivos son precisamente enseñar como hacer una buena pregunta. Que estos links no sean leidos es otra historia...