# ¿Bajo qué circunstancias puedo agregar "urgente" o frases similares a mi pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas, propuesta-de-faq

Con frecuencia tenemos personas que desean obtener rápidamente respuestas a una pregunta, y terminan añadiendo frases destinadas a obtener soluciones rápidamente. En mi experiencia, estas incluirán:

- Esto es urgente (para mi)
- ¡Por favor, respondan lo antes posible!
- Estoy bajo una fecha límite/de entrega ajustada [tal <día>]
- He estado atascado en esto por horas/días/semanas
- Mi profesor/jefe está molesto/enojado por mi entrega [potencialmente] tardía
- Estoy desesperado/me estoy arrancando el pelo
- Esperando ansiosamente una respuesta/Estoy esperando en línea

Me preguntaba si la comunidad cree que agregar estas frases podría ayudar a priorizar qué preguntas son más importantes que otras y bajo qué circunstancias, si las hay, es aceptable añadirlas.

Se me ocurre que la comunidad, por ejemplo, puede querer desalentar el uso de estas frases de manera liberal, ya que es injusto pedir ayuda urgente en caso que una tarea no está sujeta a una fecha límite próxima. Igualmente, podemos considerar que, dado que no tenemos forma de determinar si un usuario tiene realmente urgencia, preferiríamos que todos los usuarios se abstengan de este tipo de adiciones.

La comunidad puede desear considerar la posibilidad de que estas frases puedan constituir accidentalmente una expectativa para los lectores y que, en algunas culturas, esta actitud hacia los voluntarios pueda ser entendida como exigente o grosera.

Espero que algunas personas mantengan la opinión de que la adición de estas frases en realidad no hace ninguna diferencia en apresurar las respuestas y que, en algunos casos, puede atraer votos negativos (ya sea porque el votante ve una falta de concisión o sienten que es inapropiado apresurar a los voluntarios)  y puede desmotivar a quién está en capacidad de escribir una respuesta útil para el autor de la pregunta.

[Volver al índice de preguntas frecuentes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378)

**<sup>1</sup>**: Con información de [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/255257)

---

**Vínculo canónico:**
`[¿Bajo qué circunstancias puedo agregar "urgente" o frases similares a mi pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4771)`

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Muy buena publicación! Gracias jachguate por ponerla. Lo suyo será entonces crear una continuación que solicite el bloqueo de esta palabra de los títulos, tal y como ahora estamos pidiendo en [Prohibamos la palabra “ayuda” en los títulos de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759/83)

Comment: @Pikoh en realidad asumí que al convertir la pregunta en CW, la respuesta automáticamente sería también CW. De hecho, al momento de realizar la publicación marqué el checkbox para ello, y dado que publiqué la pregunta y la respuesta a la vez, también esperaba que ocurriera entonces. Por lo mismo, agradezco que también la respuesta sea _convertida_ en CW. Un saludo!

Comment: @jachguate cualquier usuario puede convertir su respuesta en CW. Puedes simplemente marcar el checkbox al crearla, o tras editarla (esto último no puedo confirmartelo, pero diría que si). De todas maneras en este caso ya lo hice yo. Un saludo :)

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh, lo marqué al publicar (pregunta y respuesta a la vez). Recuerdo haber verificado y había un único checkbox en la parte inferior que supuse aplicaría para ambas –pregunta y respuesta–. Lo marqué casi al final, y luego de publicar me dí cuenta que ambas habían quedado bajo mi autoría. Luego recordé que en el índice de las FAQ decía que había que solicitar a un moderador la conversión. Al final, no es la idea ponerles más trabajo del que ya tienen, gracias por la paciencia! Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate ni mucho menos. Para eso estamos ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No lo hagas nunca

En el mejor de los casos, esto es solo *ruido* en la pregunta y realmente se interpone en el camino de expresar la pregunta real. **Esto dificulta que las personas te ayuden**, lo que hace que sea menos probable que obtengas una respuesta.

Casi nadie, al ver que necesitas una respuesta **lo antes posible**, dejará todo lo que está haciendo para ayudarte. Tus emergencias son tuyas. Alternativamente: la falta de planificación de tu parte no constituye una emergencia para mi.

En el peor de los casos, será visto como muy grosero. Específicamente decir que tus necesidades son urgentes o que necesitas una respuesta lo antes posible **implica que tu tiempo es más valioso que el tiempo de otras personas que hacen preguntas, o ¡de las personas que responden preguntas!**

Otras personas que hacen preguntas quieren una respuesta tanto como tú. Las personas que responden preguntas lo hacen de forma gratuita y voluntaria, en su tiempo libre. Escribir respuestas conlleva su propia cuota de investigación, tiempo y esfuerzo. ¿Por qué es tu tiempo más valioso que el de ellos? Esto desalentará activamente a las personas a responder, y probablemente incluso obtendrás algunos votos negativos, lo que hace que sea aún menos probable que obtengas una respuesta.

Además, en mi experiencia, las publicaciones que contienen "necesito ayuda lo antes posible" y "ayuda urgente porfa" generalmente contienen otros problemas. **Hacer una investigación adecuada lleva tiempo, así que si tienes prisa, probablemente no estés haciendo la investigación adecuada.**

¿Te has tomado el tiempo para depurar el programa? ¿Te has tomado el tiempo para agregar sentencias `print`, o para reducir el problema a un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), o para leer la documentación?

Si tienes prisa, la respuesta es probablemente **no**. Y si no ha hecho estas cosas, es más difícil para nosotros ayudarte. **La mejor manera de mejorar tus posibilidades de obtener respuesta es haciéndonos más fácil responderte**. No incluir la investigación adecuada hace que sea más difícil ayudarte, lo que nuevamente disminuye sus posibilidades de obtener una respuesta.

Entre la prisa, puedes terminar escribiendo una pregunta incompleta, difícil de comprender por su mala redacción o por la falta de información importante en ella. También corres el riesgo de incluir información no relevante o fragmentos de código que requieren un esfuerzo extra de comprensión, quizás porque el problema no está suficientemente aislado y contienen *ruido*.

Puede parecer paradójico pero, si tienes prisa, lo mejor que puedes hacer es reducir la velocidad. Un viejo dicho dice: *Despacio porque precisa*, y ese aplica a la programación también.

Así que realmente **no hay razón para incluir urgencia**, y hay muchas razones para **no** incluirla.

**<sup>1</sup>**: Con información de [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/255257) de meta StackOverflow (en inglés)