# ¿Estamos utilizando demasiado poco el cierre por duplicado? ¿No usamos demasiado el de "basado en opiniones"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Acabo de mirar las [Razones de cierre específicas de la comunidad presentes y pasadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats) dentro de la zona de [Herramientas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/) disponible para usuarios con reputación de 10.000 o más. Luego, miré los datos equivalentes para Stack Overflow en inglés: [Closure statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats).

Hay bastante jugo en los datos. Me he centrado en la parte que indica qué razones de cierre se utilizan con más frecuencia.

En los últimos 90 días en SOes...

- Preguntas cerradas: 1344
- Preguntas formuladas: 15340
- Porcentaje de cierres: 8,76 %

Mientras que en SO en los últimos 30 días...

- Questions Closed: 36902
- Questions Asked: 268775
- Close percentage: 13.73 %

Suponiendo como hipótesis que Stack Overflow en inglés tiene el modelo más engrasado y que queremos ir hacia allí, vemos por ejemplo que en SO se cierra un 60% más de preguntas que en SOes.

Fijémonos ahora en los motivos más usados en SOes, ordenados de más a menos:

- 22,42 %   Basada en opiniones
- 21,16 %   Necesita detalles o aclaraciones
- 17,15 %   No adecuado para este sitio - Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable
- 10,47 %   Duplicadas
- 9,73 %    Necesita ser más específica
- 6,98 %    No adecuado para este sitio - La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.
- 6,76 %    No adecuado para este sitio - Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.
- 2,75 %    No adecuado para este sitio - Otro (añade un comentario explicando cuál es el problema)
- 1,93 %    No adecuado para este sitio - La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros,herramientas,librerías u otros recursos externos
- 0,07 %    No adecuado para este sitio - Esta pregunta pertenece a otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange

Mientras que en SO en inglés los datos son como sigue:

- 32.28 %   Duplicate
- 20.75 %   Needs details or clarity
- 15.18 %   Needs more focus
- 8.67 %    Not suitable for this site - Needs debugging details
- 5.25 %    Not suitable for this site - Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
- 4.21 %    Opinion-based
- 3.87 %    Not suitable for this site - About general computing hardware and software
- 3.63 %    Not suitable for this site - Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
- 1.98 %    Not suitable for this site - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)
- 0.68 %    Not suitable for this site - About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration
- 0.55 %    Not suitable for this site - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Veamos diferencia en cada casuística de primer nivel:

```
              SO       SOes      diferencia
duplicado     32,28%   10,47%     308,31%
+específica    9,73%   15,18%     156,01%
+detalles     21,16%   20,75%      98,06%
opiniones     22,42%   4,21%       18,78%
```

Es decir, en SO se marca como duplicado el triple que en SOes, mientras que se utiliza más de cinco veces menos el motivo de cierre de "basada en opiniones".

Dejo todos los datos por aquí (también los tengo en un fichero que podría compartir, si interesa) y paso a las posibles conclusiones:

- ¿Deberíamos intentar buscar duplicados de manera más activa?
- ¿Sería bueno editar, etiquetar, titular las preguntas para que sean más fáciles de encontrar? De esto hablé en [Al preguntar o editar escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/83)
- ¿Qué os parece, en general, que se podría hacer para ser de más ayuda?

Answer (score 4):

Creo que estamos usando poco los reportes y votos de cierre, independientemente del motivo. He visto (y votado) preguntas que no cumplen con las normas de SOes, como [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371922/mejor-forma-de-meter-datos-de-xml-a-mysql) o [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371823/por-qu%c3%a9-al-imprimir-el-disparo-este-no-sale-enfrente-del-jugador-js-phaser3), incluso he visto usuarios que publican la misma pregunta 3 o 4 veces y se quedan ahí por mucho tiempo.

Mi suposición es que cada vez hay menos usuarios que conocen el funcionamiento del sitio y, a la vez, más usuarios nuevo que no siguen las reglas, llegando a resultar fastidioso estar repitiendo "Haz el recorrido...", "Lee las normas...", "Gana tu primera medalla...", "Proporciona un ejemplo verificable...", etc. y, al final, llega el punto donde es más fácil dar un voto negativo que comentar o reportar las publicaciones de baja calidad.

Comment: No creo que sea necesario leer nada para aprender como plantear una pregunta. Una persona con criterio se da cuenta de que tiene que entregar toda la información relevante; nadie le va a leer el pensamiento.

Answer (score 2):

> - ¿Sería bueno editar, etiquetar, titular las preguntas para que sean más fáciles de encontrar?
> - ¿Qué os parece, en general, que se podría hacer para ser de más ayuda?

Uno de los inconvenientes para encontrar duplicidad es precisamente ese. Hay muchos títulos ambiguos tipo "Error de python" o personales "No me funciona este código". Pienso que se deben editar directamente ese tipo de títulos, describiendo técnicamente el caso.

Por otro lado, he hecho algunos reportes de preguntas duplicadas, pero usando del link "Reportar", el cual me parece está diseñado para [denunciar] otro tipo de eventos. ¿Es la forma correcta o es que todavía no tengo rango suficiente para sugerir que un tema es duplicado?

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo. Las respuestas son para quien pregunta, pero también para la gran cantidad de gente que lo leerá después. Y si no tiene buen título, no se encuentra.

Comment: En cuanto a votar para cerrar, es un privilegio que obtendrás en nada, cuando llegues a 3000 puntos: [emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)