# Cruzada contra los malos títulos

Tags: discusión, preguntas, ediciones, títulos-de-preguntas

Tiene tiempo que tengo mi cruzada personal contra las preguntas que contienen "ayuda" en el título. Esto es porque de manera generalizada sus títulos son una basura.

Por ejemplo apenas me hallé una pregunta con respuesta cuyo título era algo así como:

> "Ayuda con ejercicio"

Si bien muchas de ellas con sus malos títulos mayormente no obtienen respuesta, esta si tenía, lo cual me indica que quien le ayudó no se preocupó por mejorar el título. Considero a esto una buena práctica.

Sin embargo, tenía una muy buena pregunta en los comentarios que me ayudó a mejorar al menos un poco el título y esta es:

> ¿Qué quieres lograr?

Desde ese momento la pregunta se llama

[Contar todas las true y todas las false que están dentro de un array en swift](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199508/contar-todas-las-true-y-todas-las-false-que-est%c3%a1n-dentro-de-un-array-en-swift)

Que es mucho más fácil de que alguien la halle útil tanto en una consulta a un buscador, como si ve el título, además de que el título ayuda a que aparezcan preguntas relacionadas.

Lo de preguntas relacionadas creo que necesita énfasis porque no sé en donde leí que en el sitio en inglés la mayoría de usuarios nuevos llegan a hacer su pregunta y nunca más regresan, si mejoramos el título podríamos indirectamente mejorar la retención y ser de más ayuda a esas personas.

¿Qué opinan al respecto?¿Cómo deberíamos de actuar en estos casos?

Comment: ¿Duplicado? [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/65)